# Ansibe find module extra output, why and how

Tags: ansible

ansible-playbook find module shows extra output, how to quiet it.

Here is the playbook

```
---

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

  - name: "Testing if I can list the home folder"
    find:
      paths: $HOME
    register: files_matched

  - name: "Output data"
    debug:
      msg: "Testing {{ item.path }}"
    with_items: "{{ files_matched.files }}"
```

Here is the output

```
    .....
        ......
        ok: [cdl-z4-01.es.ad.adp.com] => (item={'uid': 1000, 'woth': False, 'mtime': 1450139013.0,
'inode': 1351746, 'isgid': False, 'size': 11814683, 'roth': False, 'isuid': False, 'isreg': True, 'pw_name': 'virtual', 'gid': 10, 'ischr': False, 'wusr': True, 'xoth': False, 'rusr': True, 'nlink': 1,\
'issock': False, 'rgrp': True, 'gr_name': 'wheel', 'path': '/home/virtual/buzz.war', 'xusr': False, 'atime': 1542161791.0,
'isdir': False, 'ctime': 1450139013.0, 'isblk': False, 'xgrp': False, 'dev': 2049, 'wgrp': False, 'isfifo': False, 'mode': '0640',
'islnk': False}) => {
            "msg": "Testing /home/virtual/buzz.war"
        }

        ......
        ....
```

===============

The output above shows the msg correctly.

**`However I see the ok line with hostname and extra information.`**

> Am I doing something differently?

Answer (score 0):

The output is controlled by the option [ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-stdout-callback). There are a lot of [plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html#plugin-list) to choose from. For example [minimal](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback/minimal.html#minimal-minimal-ansible-screen-output), [actionable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback/actionable.html#actionable-shows-only-items-that-need-attention) or [null](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback/null.html#null-don-t-display-stuff-to-screen). It is possible to write custom [plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#plugin-guidelines).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  Much appreciated.

I tried various plugins and they do show outputs in diff way.

The question for me is why does a simple `find` module outputs so much of extra data even though the debug statement is asking it to print just the item.path.

I understand it is the output, but controlling it should not be that complicated. 

I am missing something.  I just cant put my finger on it.

The following should not appear.
ok: [cdl-z4-01.es.ad.adp.com] => (item={'uid': 1000, 'woth': False,
})

Comment: IMHO, nobody cares that much about the output in the first place. What matters is if anything is changing once a playbook is running in production. If there are changes the playbook should trigger an alert. Then it's necessary to find out in the log what happened. Ansible is flexible, make your use-case.